# Using log4j 2 in netbeans gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, log4j2

I'm trying to debug an issue with some logging, and I cannot get it to run in Netbeans in a non-Maven project using Tomcat 8. The logging is in the java backing up a jsp taglib, and when I go to that page, I get a 500 error where the key line in the traceback seems to be "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager". The two specified libraries (log4j-api-2.13.3.jar and log4j-core-2.13.3.jar) have been added to the project, and that's about all I can find to do; the source appears to build correctly. I can't find anywhere to explicitly set a classpath for the server, so if that's the solution, I need to know how to get at that.

Comment: A NoClassDefFound error doesn't always mean that the class isn't present. A lot of the time it means that there was an error creating the class, such as initializing the static fields or executing static blocks. Do you see any other messages being logged to stdout?

Comment: Well, that's a good question. I'm not able to see stdout at all; I know that there can be a panel which shows it, but I don't know how to make it appear, and at the moment it isn't there. (Windows 10, btw)